# how to copy, or "fill" as in excel, a value up or down a certain number of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't know how to simply copy a data.frame value up or down rows by an integer.

For example, if I have this data.frame `df`:

```
randcol <- c("s","a","m","p","l", "e","d","a","t","a","h","e","l","l","o")
x <- c(NA,NA,"a",NA,NA,NA,NA,"b",NA,NA,NA,"c",NA,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(randcol, x)
```

[image]

I don't know how to `mutate()` `df$x` and copy/fill each character to `2` rows down, to achieve this new `df`:

[image]

What are some good ways? Is there a `dplyr` way?

thank you.
dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We create a grouping variable using the non-NA values in 'x' and then do the `replace`ment

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(x))) %>% 
   mutate(x = replace(x, 2:pmin(3,n()), x[1])) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 15 x 2
#   randcol x     
#   <fctr>  <fctr>
# 1 s       <NA>  
# 2 a       <NA>  
# 3 m       a     
# 4 p       a     
# 5 l       a     
# 6 e       <NA>  
# 7 d       <NA>  
# 8 a       b     
# 9 t       b     
#10 a       b     
#11 h       <NA>  
#12 e       c     
#13 l       c     
#14 l       c     
#15 o       <NA>
```

---

Or another option is to do the `fill` first and then replace the row numbers that are greater than 3 with NA after grouping by 'x'

```
df %>%
   tidyr::fill(x) %>% 
   group_by(x1 = x) %>% 
   mutate(x = case_when(row_number() >3 ~ NA_character_,
                      TRUE ~ as.character(x))) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-x1)
```